# 'Str' object is not callable, although I converted it into 'int'

Tags: python

I just started learning coding, so I'm new to everything.

I've been trying to create a program that asks the user what's the temperature on his city, and then convert it to fahrenheit, if the user's temperature is in celsius, and vice-versa.

However, when I try to call the variable 'temperature', where the user inputs his temperature, it says that I can't call a str object, although I converted it into a integer using the int() function.

How can I solve this problem?

This is my code:

```
temperature = int(input(("What's the current temperature in your city? (please type only numbers)")))


temperature_metric = input("Is it in celsius or fahrenheit?") 
while temperature_metric not in ['celsius', 'fahrenheit']:

    print("Please type 'celsius' or 'fahrenheit'.")
    temperature_metric = input()

if temperature_metric == 'celsius':
    print("Your temperature in fahrenheit is: "(9/5 * temperature) + 32)

elif temperature_metric == 'fahrenheit':
    print("Your temperature in celsius is: " ((5/9) * (temperature - 32)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two print statments are missing a comma, thats it!

```
if temperature_metric == 'celsius':
    print("Your temperature in fahrenheit is: ", (9/5 * temperature) + 32)

elif temperature_metric == 'fahrenheit':
    print("Your temperature in celsius is: " , ((5/9) * (temperature - 32)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't expect it was something so dumb xD.

Answer (score 0):

The error happens in your print statements at the end, e.g.:

```
print("Your temperature in celsius is: " ((5/9) * (temperature - 32)))
```

To break it down:

```
print("..."(expr))
```

Syntaxtically, the parameter to `print` is a function call, where the "function" is a string; that is the object the error refers to.

The other answers already show how to fix this, here are some ways:

- use string concatenation with `+`, which requires two strings: `print("message " + str(temperature))`
- use separate parameters to `print`: `print("message", temperature)`. Note that I left out the space, as `print` inserts a space between parameters.
- use format string syntax: `print(f"message {temperature}")`

I personally prefer the third one, because it doesn't depend on printing and keeps the message rather tidy.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't convert the integer part in the `if-elif`. You can either print just integer or string values. To print integer along with string values you need to convert the integer to string using `str()`. So the code should look like:

```
temperature = int(input(("What's the current temperature in your city? (please type only numbers)")))


temperature_metric = input("Is it in celsius or fahrenheit?") 
while temperature_metric not in ['celsius', 'fahrenheit']:

    print("Please type 'celsius' or 'fahrenheit'.")
    temperature_metric = input()

    if temperature_metric == 'celsius':
        print("Your temperature in fahrenheit is: " + str((9/5 * temperature) + 32))

    elif temperature_metric == 'fahrenheit':
        print("Your temperature in celsius is: " + str(((5/9) * (temperature - 32))))
```